ShareX recorded long video cannot quickly jump to a given timestamp
I saw that here are asked questions related to encoding and ShareX, so I decided to ask in this portal.
Basically I recorded video using ShareX 16.1. ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg version n7.0-14-g2d3ee7c069-20240423 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.26.0.65_ecc5e41)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdvdread --enable-libdvdnav --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --cc=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --cxx=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --ar=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar --ranlib=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib --nm=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm --extra-version=20240423
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
Universal media converter
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Settings inside ShareX are:


On last screen you can see, that I copied additional command line arguments for recording with microphone.
I recorded 2h video and was happy to watch the material the next day, but when I opened VLC or Media Player Classic (latest version) and wanted to jump to 1 h 5 min of video it took about ~10 minutes to get there...
Not sure whether this issue is related with NVENC (I have 3770k and GTX1070ti, so I decided to use GPU, this CPU is getting overwhelmed with various programs and stuff) or if it's just ShareX behaviour.
It seems very strange that ShareX recordings do not seek quickly. Basically If I go to 01:05:00 it takes about ~10 minutes. And then I want to go to 01:30:00 and it will take again enourmous amount of time.
Just as if this video was recorded using 'monolythic' block and not in 'chunks' so jumping takes enourmous amount of time.
What do I need to add to make seeking work fast? I am guessing maybe I should add something inside Additional command line arguments, just like for normal YouTube movie or any movie from any service e.g. Netflix? Or, unlikely, maybe I can't do this?
I am also open to other suggestions with encoding and various parameters, but the main culprit is this jumping issue.

This question is very confusing. Let's start with the fact that there's no such thing as "recording's fast-forwarding feature"... Fast forwarding is implemented by the player itself. What exactly are you using in VLC? Also, your ffmpeg is outdated, always try updating first.

Basically If I download video from YT and it is 2h and I want to go to moment 1:05:05 it basically instantly go there in VLC I don't have to wait 10minutes. But If I recorded that using Sharex and wanted to go to moment 1:05:05 I would have to wait ~10minutes. Sorry my English is a little bit rusty and not my native language, maybe I didn't described it correctly it would make more sense...

How should I name it if not 'fast-forwarding'? Going to given moment in video? English is not my native language.

That's seeking/jumping not fast-forwarding. Please edit to clarify. Try also adding -g 60 to change keyframe interval and check if that helps.

will check, thanks @Destroy666

I used to witness this kind of slow jumping when a video file had a bad/nonexisting index. The player would end up having to decode every frame internally upto the point i jumped to.  Looking through the extensive list of ffmpeg options, the one that confuses me most is the zerolatency tune. However, as usual, try to tone down the options to the bare minimum to seek out the culprit (encode without sound for example). Removing options for debugging purposes is your best bet, as there are so many ffmpeg versions and settings its a guessing game what might be causing it.

I just tested it and used -g 60 and it fixed the issue. You can add answer @Destroy666 I will accept it and you will get points etc.

One way to possibly get seeking issues fixed is to ensure there are enough keyframes in the video, as video players often use those to jump to specific time chosen by the user. They first find the closest keyframe, then decode more optimized frames until the time is reached.
To make sure the encoder is including enough keyframes, you can add -g 60 to ShareX ffmpeg additional args option. This param specifies number of frames between 2 keyframes. 60 with 30 FPS means we are adding a keyframe every 2 seconds, so at most less than 2 seconds will need to be decoded.
Of course smaller GOP means bigger file size as more keyframes = more full frames in your video.

It worked! Thanks again.
